# div tag for making portion at bottom right most

Tags: html

How can I make a right most division in the bottom div as shown in given code like a small square box with in a box at right side using only html div tag? Also tell me how to adjust its size.

```html
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Vendors</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheet.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div align="top" style="width:940;height:400;border:solid;border-width:4;">
        <center><p>My top  five Vendors</p></center>
        <button>Click me</button>

</div>



<div class="bottom" align="bottom" style="height:350;width:940;border:solid">



    <div align="left" style="height:350;width:470;border:solid">
        <div align="bottom" style="height:175;width:467;border:solid">

        </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your [HTML is invalid](http://validator.w3.org/), and your [CSS is invalid](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) - try going to basic automated QA.

Comment: how can u say this ?? plz tell me a valid reason.

Comment: I can say it because I know HTML and CSS well enough to spot some of the many errors you have made when I glance at your code. I linked to validators, try using them.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your HTML and CSS you should probably try to position the  like that:

```
<style>
div#bottomRight{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right: 0: //or whatever value fits your needs
width: 200px; //or whatever value fits your needs
height: 50px; //or whatever value fits your needs
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add 'px' to your width and height values. See demo here http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/dy5us/

```
<body>
    <div align="top" style="width:940px;height:400px;border:solid;border-width:4px;">
        <center><p>My top  five Vendors</p></center>
        <button>Click me</button>

</div>



<div class="bottom" align="bottom" style="height:350px;width:940px;border:solid">



    <div align="left" style="height:350px;width:470px;border:solid">
        <div align="bottom" style="height:175px;width:467px;background:red;">

        </div>

</div>

</body>
```